# Integrating Matplotlib Charts into Angular Web Application

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently, I've been working with the **matplotlib** Python library to fulfill a requirement of **integrating matplotlib charts into a web application built on Angular**.

Initially, my plan was to serve the matplotlib chart image to a web application from the **python flask server**. In this requirement, the matplotlib chart is updated every second. So, a new image file has to be created every second, And that has to be sent to the web application. So it seems this approach is inefficient and unsuitable for meeting the requirements.

Now, I'm actively searching for a better solution to integrate matplotlib with the web application. If anyone has any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this, please let me know.

if there is a way to **visualize matplotlib charts using Grafana panels**. If anyone has experience or knowledge in this area, Please guide me to achieve my requirement.

Comment: If `matplotlib` is not a must, I think I've heard Plotly might be a better solution for web applications.

Comment: @fakedad I tried with Plotly, and that works fine. what I have to know, is if there is any way to integrate matplotlib chart with a web application directly using some packages. or if there is any way to integrate matplotlib chart with grafana panels.